# regex: Don't match after a character

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

This transforms

```
word word1 https://sub.example.org/file/track?arg=par word
```

to

```
https://sub.example.org/file/track?arg=par
```

Desired result:

```
https://sub.example.org/file/track
```

Comment: One should never use a regex than is more than 1.5 kms. in length.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0):

With only one example to work off:

```
^.* (https?:\/\/.*?)\?.*$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Search: ".* (.*)\?.*"
Replace: "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
"(https:[^ ]*)"
```

and replacing with

```
"$1"
```

The regular expression `https:[^ ]*` says "Look for a substring which begins with 'https:' and is followed by zero or more character which are *NOT* a space". The parentheses around the regular expression says "Treat everything inside these parentheses as a 'match group'". The replacement string "$1" says "Replace everything with match group #1" - or, in other words, everything inside the parentheses, which in this case is everything in the original string which matched the regular expression. [See this regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/CmblgP/1).

The `[^x]` construct, where `x` is a character which should NOT appear in the matched data, is a very common construct in regular expressions, and IMO is one you should remember and use.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following regular expression:

```
https:.*(?=\?)(?!=.+\?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/alhWMm/1/)

This PCRE (PHP) regex performs the following operations:

```
https:     # Match string
.*         # Match 0+ chars
(?=\?)     # Use a positive lookahead to match a following '?'
(?!=.+\?)  # Use a negative lookahead to avoid matching '?' after 1+ chars
```

The negative lookahead is needed in case a directory or file name contains a question mark. (Recall that, while Windows does does not permit file names to contain question marks, Unix/OSX/Linux does.)

For example, in the string were

```
word word1 https://sub.example?.org/file/track?arg=par word
```

this regex would match

```
https://sub.example?.org/file/track
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match the following regular expression:

```
http[^\?]+
```

- `[^\?]+` -> will match all except "?"

[image]